# Python: self.P = {s: {a: [] for a in range(nA)} for s in range(nS)}

Tags: python

I am stuck at [line no. 157 of this github code](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/toy_text/frozen_lake.py#L157).

```
self.P = {s: {a: [] for a in range(nA)} for s in range(nS)}
```

I am not familiar with the syntax of python. Can anybody please help me understand what this code does? Does it create a blank 2d list of size nA rows and nS columns?

Comment: Have you played around with that line of code (setting some values for nA and nS) to find out?

Comment: It's nested dictionary comprehensions.

Comment: To extend: a nested dictionary comprehension with integer values as keys (because of the use of `range`). It probably mimics a two-dimensional array/list, in that you can then access elements with `P[2][3]`. A normal two-dimensional list, or something else altogether, would make more sense (without knowing the context).